# pthread, pointers and more headache in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I'm trying to get the total count of the iterations in a loop which is broken-down into threads, in C. Using a global var(lock/unlock), a global var[NUM_THREADS], both work (the first is much slower tho); but the code below does not work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define THREADS 8

void *loop(void *ptr);

int main()
{
    clock_t ts = clock();
    pthread_t th[THREADS];
    long long lsum[THREADS] = {0};

    for (int t = 0; t < THREADS; t++)
    {
        pthread_create(&th[t], NULL, loop, (void *)&lsum[t]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
    }

    long long tsum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++)
    {
        tsum += lsum[i];
    }

    clock_t te = clock();
    printf("%.3f%s\n", (float)(te - ts) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, " Seconds");
    printf("%lld", tsum);
}

void *loop(void *ptr)
{
    long long *counter = ptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000 / THREADS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
        {
            i - (i / (j + 1)) + j *j;
            *counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

tsum output is zero. Is this something about casting back and forth the passed pointer in pthread_create? or it's all wrong to use this method?

Comment: What is the purpose of the thread functions? What are they supposed to do? What will happen with the statement `i - (i / (j + 1)) + j *j;`?

Comment: Also note that even though you don't use the value that the thread returns, the function *is* declared to return something and you don't do that. That leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used to think that too, but turns out it's only UB if the return value is actually used, see [C11 6.9.1p12](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p12).  Still bad style though.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the function does not do anything special. Just wanted to do some lengthy calculations to see how multithreading affects execution time.

Comment: @user9814319 When you do this sort of test, you must make sure that the result of the 'lengthy calculation' is actually used somehow, or else the compiler is liable to not bother generating machine code for it.

Comment: @zwol I've just started to learn C (oding). And learned a lot from you answers and comments. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `++` has higher operator precedence than unary `*`, you are incrementing *counter*, not the array element that counter points to.  If you change the line

```
*counter++;
```

to read either

```
(*counter)++;
```

or

```
*counter += 1;
```

then `tsum` will wind up being 10000000000 as you expected.

The language is defined this way because it's much more common to write things like

```
while (*p) *q++ = *p++;
```

where you *want* the pointers to be incremented.

Comment: In other words, it's a problem of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: And once corrected, the compiler could just optimize the thread function to `*counter = 1000000 / THREADS * 10000;` or plain `*counter = 1250000000;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think that's just an artifact of being shown a cut-down example program.  The real thing would do something meaningful in that loop.

Comment: yes! that is something which I missed while I knew it! but by just changing it to (*counter)++, the execution time jumped from 4 sec to 37 secs!! why?

Comment: @user9814319 Because now you are performing an actual write to memory on each iteration.  Before that change, the compiler might've been able to optimize away the entire body of `loop`.

Comment: @zwol incrementing the `counter` itself isn't an actual write to memory?

Comment: No, `counter` is in a register, and also the compiler can figure out that it's write-only and not do the increments at all.